# Strange DefaultTreeCellRenderer behaviour, only partially executing getTreeCellRendererComponent()

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treecellrenderer

I created a JTree, even with multiple root nodes (what was quite hard for me, as it's my first JTree), and was ready (I thought) to go one step further; a cellrenderer.

I tried to set one icon for every node, it worked fine. Now I'm trying to check what kind of node it is (not only leaf and branch), and building a String of the filename of the image I want. `isKlas()` always returns true for now, so it should be klas_fold.png OR klas_unfold.png. BUT the `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` is only partially executed because the filepath never gets printed, nor is any icon changed, it's always the default!

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RATree extends JTree {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3855798479619346917L;

    public RATree(Object[] top) {
        super(top);
        MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer();
        this.setCellRenderer(renderer);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
    }

    protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {

        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    class MyRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            TreeItem node;
            String fileName = "";
            super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            try {
                node = (TreeItem) value;
            }
            catch (ClassCastException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return this;
            }

            if(node.isKlas()) {
                fileName += "klas_";
            }

            if(expanded) {
                fileName += "unfold.png";
                this.setIcon(createImageIcon("../bin/" + fileName));
            }
            else {
                fileName += "fold.png";
                this.setIcon(createImageIcon("../bin/" + fileName));
            }

            System.out.println("fileName: " + fileName); //Doesn't get executed, or at least, I can't see it.
            return this;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example");
        Object[] root = {new TreeItem("name", "someURL"), new TreeItem("name", "someUrl")};
        f.add(new RATree(root));
        f.setSize(100,100);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Yes, it's an inner class.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I found out it was a ClassCastException that screwed things. But that's strange, because I initialize the Tree like this: `new JTree({new TreeItem("params"), new TreeItem("params")});`. So I should be able to cast them back from Object to TreeItem? (TreeItem iis one of my classes. It extends DefaultMutableTreeNode).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Load & cache the images when the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` is constructed.

Comment: Great idea, would never have came up with a `SSCCE` myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it myself! I thought that `Object value` was the TreeItem I put in the JTree, but it was something else. I got the TreeItem by doing this (like in the Customizing a Tree's display link supplied by mKorbel):

```
TreeItem node = (TreeItem) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).getUserObject();
```

Answer (score 4):

1) are you tried to notified TreeModel `TreeModel.nodeChanged(node);` that value changed

2) put `Icon(s)` directly to the TreeModel, not to re_create inside `TreeCellRenderer`

3) `JTree` (`JTable`, `JList` and `JList` from `JComboBox`) to share the same [concept as Renderer for JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

4) please to read [Customizing a Tree's Display](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display)

5) examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm) and [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/pkg.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you figured out the try-catch part. To solve the problem, make sure you are not supplying your DefaultTreeModel anything other than an instance of TreeItem. You should put this line `System.out.println(value.getClass())` in your catch block.

Also, you should consider creating a single instance of your Icons instead of making a new one each time a tree node is expanded or collapsed.

Comment: `System.out.println(value.getClass());` gices me the output :
`class javax.swing.JTree$DynamicUtilTreeNode`